# Set text input placeholder color in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, styles, placeholder

When using ordinary CSS if you want to style your place holder you use these css selectors :

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

But I can't figure out how to apply these type of styles in react inline styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use [radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium)

```
var Radium = require('radium');
var React = require('react');
var color = require('color');

@Radium
class Button extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    kind: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['primary', 'warning']).isRequired
  };

  render() {
    // Radium extends the style attribute to accept an array. It will merge
    // the styles in order. We use this feature here to apply the primary
    // or warning styles depending on the value of the `kind` prop. Since its
    // all just JavaScript, you can use whatever logic you want to decide which
    // styles are applied (props, state, context, etc).
    return (
      <button
        style={[
          styles.base,
          styles[this.props.kind]
        ]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

// You can create your style objects dynamically or share them for
// every instance of the component.
var styles = {
  base: {
    color: '#fff',

    // Adding interactive state couldn't be easier! Add a special key to your
    // style object (:hover, :focus, :active, or @media) with the additional rules.
    ':hover': {
      background: color('#0074d9').lighten(0.2).hexString()
    },
    '::-webkit-input-placeholder' {
        color: red;
    }
  },

  primary: {
    background: '#0074D9'
  },

  warning: {
    background: '#FF4136'
  }
};
```

Comment: this does not work for me. btw, you're missing a `:` on your `'::-webkit-input-placeholder'` json object

Comment: No need to use radium package. You can do this without doing it. Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70471012/how-to-use-ms-reveal-as-inline-style-in-react/70480538#70480538

Answer (score 15):

Simply give your "input" tag an "id" or a "class" and put your css style in App.css inside src. e.g

```
//App.css or external stylesheet

#inputID::placeholder {
    color: #ff0000;
    opacity: 1;
}

//your jsx code
<input type="text" id="inputID" placeholder="Your text here" />
```

That actually worked for me.

Comment: This isn't any different from what the OP already did. He is asking how to do this with inline HTML

Answer (score 10):

**You can't use `::-webkit-inline-placeholder` inline.**

It is a pseudo-element that (much like e.g. `:hover`) can only be used in your stylesheet:

> The non-standard proprietary `::-webkit-input-placeholder` pseudo-element represents the placeholder text of a form element.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-input-placeholder)

**Instead, assign a class to the React component** via the `className` property and apply the style to this class.

Comment: Alternative method for using pseudo-element without creating css file. Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70480538/9282474

Answer (score 3):

Do not use ::-webkit-inline-placeholder inline and Radium for one placeholder.

I suggest go to your index.css

```
input.yourclassname::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: white;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach is to simply apply different styles to the entire `<input />` component based on whether or not the value is empty.  No need to install a new dependency, and no need to use a stylesheet which seems to be the point of the original question.

```
var inputStyles = {
    border: '1px solid #cbcbcb',
    color: '#525252',
};
var placeholderStyles = {
    ...inputStyles,
    color: '#999999',
};
```

```
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="enter text here"
    value={myValue}
    style={myValue ? inputStyles : placeholderStyles}
/>
```

Comment: But the `color` style doesn't change the input placeholder's color...

Comment: @Yairopro, this example worked for me at the time I posted this.  I would cite these resources which seem to corroborate that the `color` property is correct:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder and
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use [Radium's Style component](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/tree/master/docs/api#style-component). Here's what you can do in ES6 syntax:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Radium, { Style } from 'radium'

class Form extends Component {
   render() {
      return (<div>
         <Style scopeSelector='.myClass' rules={{
            '::-webkit-input-placeholder': {
               color: '#929498'
            }}} />
         <input className='myClass' type='text' placeholder='type here' />
      </div>
   }
}

export default Radium(Form)
```

Comment: this doesnt work either https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/243#issuecomment-230034996

Answer (score 0):

Use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) i.e. ``` Backward quotes(``) ``` for adding your pseudo-element.

```
const inputFieldStyle = `
           .inputField::-webkit-input-placeholder{
                   color: red;
           }`
```

Using `class` is important thing so make sure you used class before pseudo-element.

Then you can use  tag where you pass above style like below:

```
const reactFunctionalComponent = (props) => {
  ...
  return(
    <>
      <style>
        {inputFieldStyle}
      </style>
    ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that provides pseudo selector functionality in React, without relying on a third party library, in about 20 lines of code.

This is an extension of [RohitSawai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70480584/480608) that injects a `<style>` tag, but in a more encapsulated and reusable fashion.

Define this function once in your project:

```js
/** Returns a unique className and injectStyle function that can be used to 
style pseudo elements. Apply the className to the desired element and render 
injectStyle() nearby. The pseudo selector, e.g. ::-webkit-input-placeholder, 
will be appended to the unique className, styling a pseudo element directly, 
or a descendant pseudo element, as determined by the selector. */
const pseudo = (pseudoSelector, style) => {
  const className = `pseudo-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)}`

  // simple encoding of style dictionary to CSS
  // for simplicity, assumes that keys are already in slug case and units have 
  // been added, unlike React.CSSProperties
  const styleCSS =
    '{' +
    Object.entries(style)
      .map(([name, value]) => `${name}: ${value};`)
      .join('') +
    '}'

  return {
    className,
    injectStyle: () => (
      <style>
        {`.${className}${pseudoSelector} ${styleCSS}`}
      </style>
    )
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const placeholder = pseudo('::-webkit-input-placeholder', { color: 'red' })

  return (<div>
    {placeholder.injectStyle()}
    <input className={placeholder.className} placeholder="This placeholder is red" />
  </div>)
}
```