# React change placeholder text color using React inline styling

Tags: css, reactjs

How can I change placeholder text color with React inline styling? I'm using the following input styling:

```
input: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      border: '0px',
      float: 'left',
      paddingLeft: '30px',
      ...
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate [**Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set text input placeholder color in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922878/set-text-input-placeholder-color-in-reactjs)

Comment: None of "possible duplicate" links answer my question. I'm trying to do this in pure React with React inline styling and I don't want to use Radium.

Comment: @foobar You can't change pseudo element styles with React inline styles. You either have to use the third party library (likes of Radium) or add `className` to your `input` and style it's pseudo element through CSS file.

Comment: @Swordys, thank you for the answer, and apologies for the question

Answer (score 1):

You can simply target the placeholder text inside the attribute like so:

```
 input::placeholder {
     color: white;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a single space that sits between the selector and className, so I had to do this to achieve.

Please refer to this, https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/712

```
        <Style
            scopeSelector=""
            rules={{
                '.textfield-input::placeholder': { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
                    color: 'red',
                    opacity: 1 /* Firefox */
                },

                '.textfield-input:-ms-input-placeholder': { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
                    color: 'red',
                },

                '.textfield-input::-ms-input-placeholder': { /* Microsoft Edge */
                    color: 'red',
                }
            }}
        />
```